# How can I convert a WAV from stereo to mono in Python?

Tags: python, audio, wav

I don't want to use any other apps (like sox) - I want to do this in pure Python. Installing needed Python libs is fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the WAV file is PCM-encoded then you can use [`wave`](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html). Open the source and destination files, read samples, average the channels, and write them out.

Comment: Seems like this no longer installs in my attempts, but was able to get Jiaaro's pydub to work.

Comment: There's nothing to install. It comes with Python.

Comment: You don't need to set the parameters. They will be read from the file.

Answer (score 59):

I maintain an open source library, [pydub](http://pydub.com), which make this pretty simple

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("/path/to/file.wav")
sound = sound.set_channels(1)
sound.export("/output/path.wav", format="wav")
```

One caveat: it uses ffmpeg to handle audio format conversions, but if you only use wav it can be pure python.

Comment: Thanks!
Surely that should be set_channels(1) for stereo->mono?

Comment: I love the simplicity of the package. Tried with Google Speech API on the mono output. The transcription was lower with pydub compare to using scipy to split channels. Not systematically tested though.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is using the PyTorch [mean](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mean.html) function as in the example below.

```
import torch
import torchaudio

def stereo_to_mono_convertor(signal):
    # If there is more than 1 channel in your audio
    if signal.shape[0] > 1:
        # Do a mean of all channels and keep it in one channel
        signal = torch.mean(signal, dim=0, keepdim=True)
    return signal

# Load audio as tensor
waveform, sr = torchaudio.load('audio.wav')
# Convert it to mono channel
waveform = stereo_to_mono_convertor(waveform)
```